# Dual citizens traveling to Mexico

Tags: usa, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, dual-nationality, mexico

Hey I’m an Dual citizen and my question is I’m going to Mexico in July but I don’ have a current us passport but I do have a Mexican passport. I can’t get MY us passport renewed since I owe Child  support. Can I fly from Chicago to Guadalajara using my Mexican passport and retrurn through Tijuana San Diego using my sentri card ?

Comment: You have plenty of time to get your US passport.

Comment: I owe child support so I can’t renew my us passport

Comment: Hmm. You should expect to get some grief at the US border, but I suppose they can't really refuse you entry.

Comment: I just want to save time and money I originally was gonna do Chicago sand Diego then cross walking to tj then fly to Guadalajara and viceversa but then I was just thinking about flying to Gdl from Chicago using my Mexican passport and flying back from Guadalajara through TJ and San Diego using my sentri card

Comment: Crossing at CBX? That's probably the easiest thing to do.

Comment: Yea that’s what I was gonna do but my question really is if I exit the us only using my Mexican passport or do I have to show them the us one cuz I really wanted to save time and money. I don’t wanna be pulled aside by a homeland security officer

Comment: The chances of you being pulled aside are pretty close to 100% no matter what you do, with the exception of straightening out your child support and getting your passport back. Like I said, they'll let you back in eventually but not before they've asked you a lot of difficult questions.